# Ubuntu Software Center missing

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 9.10 from 9.04 and I can't seem to find the Ubuntu Software Center. Is there a way I can get it to Show? In Synaptic it is installed, but can't find it anyware. I also tried to re-install it in Synaptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new menu item entry with the following values:

- **Type:** Application
- **Name:** Ubuntu Software Center
- **Command:** `/usr/bin/software-center`
- **Comment:** Lets you choose from thousands of free applications available for Ubuntu
- **Icon:** `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/softwarecenter.png`

For the icon, you must click on the icon (top left)

That way, the menu entry will be recreated.